# jQuery selector: How to fuzzy match attribute

Tags: jquery

```
<div data-section-a="aaa"></div>
<div data-section-b="bbb"></div>
<div data-section-c="ccc"></div>
```

How do I select all of the above `DIV`s that all have an attribute starting with "data-section-"?

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if you could add a common class or data attribute to it. So it you can edit the source, that might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet below `r` holds all the elements you seek (`$r` holds jQuery objects)

```js
const r = []
const a = jQuery("body").find("div").each(function(i, e) {
  const attrs = e.attributes
  let l = attrs.length
  var attr;

  while (l--) {
    attr = attrs[l];
    if (attr.name.includes("data-section-")) {
      r.push(e)
    }
    console.log(attr.name + '="' + attr.value + '"');
  }
})

console.log('simple elements:', r)

// transforming to an array that holds jQuery objects
const $r = r.map(e => $(e))
console.log('jQuery elements:', $r)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-section-a="aaa"></div>
<div data-section-b="bbb"></div>
<div data-section-c="ccc"></div>
<div data-nonsection-d="ddd"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you’d better use a filter:

```
const sections = $('div').filter(function() {
  for(let data in $(this).data()) {
    if (data.indexOf('section') === 0) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
})
```